# What exactly is the Bahnhofsmission? What do they do and who uses their services?

Tags: trains, germany

I was changing trains at Frankfurt Hbf and it was a a bit cold outside (close to 0°C).  I asked at the information desk if there was any heated waiting area, and they told me this was only available at the *Bahnhofsmission* at platform 1, door 7.  I walked over there.  The door was closed (I don't know if it was locked) but there was a bell and I could see light and people inside, but they did not look like travellers.  I did not ring.

What is the function of the *Bahnhofsmission*?  From [their website](https://www.bahnhofsmission.de/Welcome.312.0.html), it appears to be a charity with a broad scope, but rather for people in trouble than for a traveller who would appreciate a bit of warmth.  Is it only for emergencies?  What do they actually do?

Comment: Haven't you answered your own question? At UK stations waiting rooms have been replaced by cafes. Although many are just stalls without a seating area. I suggest making yourself scarce in a nearby hotel.

Comment: I've never had anything to do with them but from their page it seems like their services differ from train station to train station. However, they say they help people looking for a place to rest or to stay. I don't know whether there are any conditions on that but asking would be certainly worth a try.

Comment: I find the whole Frankfurt Hbf rather warm even in winter and even tho it is very open, but as long as you are under the big dome it feels like it is somewhat climated

Comment: @WeatherVane no he hasn't. It's unclear whether it's only open to travelers with a valid ticket, homeless people, anyone in need. Makes a difference. Hamburg Hbf. used to be full of sleeping junkies locked in at night. Whether the Bahnhofsmission is safe, let alone a good idea, would depend a lot.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The *Bahnhofsmission* (train station mission, mission in the religious sense) is over 100 years old and began as a Christian network to help out young girls moving into the cities who were searching for work and were prone to be exploited for low/unpaid work or prostitution. Train stations were hot points for social problems because they connected and still connect people coming from everywhere.

The *Bahnhofsmission* tries to help *everyone* (!) with *everything* (!) without looking at their backgrounds and uses both staff and volunteer workers. It starts by you asking them for a pencil, for a map, or for a warm place and it ends with support if your train is out of order, the train had an accident, or you are the victim of a crime. As a Christian organisation, it is supported by both by Roman Catholic and the German Protestant churches. For this reason, you can expect a religious environment: bible and crosses. As clarified in the comments, this does not mean that they try to evangelise,
they simply want to convince by action, not by words. They will gladly talk about their background and the Christian idea if you are curious and interested, but if you don't want to be bothered with that, they won't bother you.

[image]

*Logo of Bahnhofsmission*

Given the extremely broad mission (essentially they are do-it-all) and the different people involved, it is often quite perplexing because you can find beggars, stranded people, and normal tourists. It is also said without a word that more important problems are tackled first, so, if you only need information, it could take some time.

Comment: From the last sentence in your second paragraph one could think they are trying to missionize, however the wikipedia article says "Religiös motivierte Seelsorge steht nicht immer im Vordergrund, sondern eher praktische Handreichungen ungeachtet der eigenen Weltanschauung; gleichwohl sind Kreuz und Bibel durchaus in einer Bahnhofsmission zu finden."

Comment: I cannot deduce this conclusion from my description. It uses the word *mission*, but the idea is: less words, but more action. Show, not tell. They will tell you about their background and talk about the christian idea if you are curious and interested, but if you don't want to be bothered with that, they won't bother you.

Comment: Note that I used *could think* and not *deduce*, because it's more of a pragmatical issue and people reading your answer (again: not everybody) might be wondering why you mention this. So I thought it was worth pointing out that there's nothing to be scared of and nobody will be forced to pray or to be baptized.

Comment: Back in the 80s I can remember they offered some care of children that traveled alone (get them into the train, wait at stations where you switch trains etc.), not sure if they still do that though.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Not only in the 80s and not only children. They still do that. I watched that (at Frankfurt, actually) about two years ago, where people from the Bahnhofsmission accompanied (separately) a blind person and a person walking with crutches to their train, helped them enter, got them seated, asked people seated around them to look out for them and only after that left.

Comment: Did you mean *voluntary* (of free will, typically but not always for no pay) rather than *honorary* (of honor)?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I mean *ehrenamtlich* which means you do the work for your own convinction without payment (You may get some presents or small sums of money, but it is not your sustenance.

Comment: @ThorstenS. *ehrenamtlich* means "voluntary", not "honorary".

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Isn't all (legal) work in German voluntary by your definition?

Comment: @errantlinguist The oxford dictionary disagrees with you. [honorary: (of an office or its holder) unpaid](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/honorary). I guess you're American?

Comment: @Voo That is a different thing. _Honorary_ refers to holding an office (usually one seen as quite prestigious and _honorable_, and most commonly one that is appointed or elected), but not being paid to carry out the work required by the office—it just gives you something fancy to write on your CV. It’s a subtype of volunteer work. If you’re a doctor who does unpaid extra work for a charity hospital, you may be an honorary doctor there, but no one would call someone who volunteers at a soup kitchen an honorary worker. The workers described here would be called volunteers, not honoraries.

Comment: @Janus Fair point.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The difference you mentioned is highly interesting. Both a honorary consul and a soup kitchen worker are *ehrenamtlich*, the distinction you mentioned *does not exist in the German language*. So why does this distinction exist in anglophone countries and why it is considered "fancy" for your CV?

Comment: @ThorstenS. why are *kostenlos*, *gratis* and *frei* all translated into English as *free*?-- asking for reasons why semantic distinctions exist in the lexicon of one language but not in another will usually lead to speculation at best.

Answer (score 12):

As Thorsten pointed out in his answer, the Bahnhofsmission is a charity. From their historical origins, they have become one of the main sources of support for those homeless people who do not want to deal with the welfare bureaucracy for some reason.

Some travelers may not feel comfortable with the other applicants in a Bahnhofsmission, especially if there are language barriers. But if you have a problem and you can't/won't solve it by spending money (e.g. on a taxi and a hotel bed) going there could be a good idea.